# ZipFile API throws error when opening file

Tags: extract, unzip, zip, winzip

**"zipfile"** throws an error for ExtractToDirectory and all other functions when extracting files of huge size **(> 1GB)**.
Error: Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.'

```
string zipPath = @"C:\Users\ABC\Work\sample.exe";
string extractPath = @"C:\Users\ABC\Work\New\";
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Note: The file is not corrupted as it can be extracted using 7zip.